# I want to ask about the Integration Connectors section in billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, integration, platform

I didn't install Integration Connectors, so why am I being charged for this cost? How can I disable it? Because I find the price too high. Thank you.

[[my billing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVWw4.png)]
[[APIs Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSqib.png)]

I hope to delete the Integration Connectors service in Google Cloud Platform. Because its price is high for me currently